# Define order of "Parallelizable" in NUnit

Tags: nunit

Im having 4 test classes inside one project (Lets call them `Class A, Class B, Class C, Class D`)

Each of these 3 classes have two `[TestFixture("string")]`, which makes it to 8 tests in total.

All classes are having the `[Parallelizable]` parameter.

When i start the test all at once by clicking inside the Test Explorer on the name of the project and "Run", then it will start all 8 tests at the same time.

The problem here is, that it consumes a lot RAM and the tests fail because it takes too long to load and i get a timeout error (Im doing automation tests with selenium in chrome)

Now i want to define a order.

For example:

- Class A and Class B should start parallel
- Class C and Class D should start parallel when Class A and Class B is done

Is it possible?

I tried the parameter `[Order(1)]` for `Class A` and `Class B` and `Order(2)]` for `Class C` and `Class D`

But when i run the tests, all 8 tests start to load.

Example from my code:

```
        [TestFixture("normalUser")]
        [TestFixture("adminUser")]
        [Parallelizable]
        public class ImportTest
        {
           private IWebDriver webDriver;
           private const int waitTimer = 60;
           public WebDriverWait w;
           public string userRole;

        // Constructor
        public ImportTest(string userRole)
        {
            this.userRole = userRole;
            Console.WriteLine(userRole);
        }

        ////-----------------------------
        [SetUp]
        {

        }
        //-------------------------------
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Do Test
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Do Test
        }
        //--------------------------

        [TearDown]
        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            webDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll describe what's happening...

The `OrderAttribute` was created in NUnit V2, before parallel tests existed. It defines the order in which tests are *started*. Since there was no parallelism at the time, one test had to finish before the next one started.

When parallel execution was introduced in NUnit 3, Order was not exactly broken, because it continued to start tests in the specified order. But many users perceptions were "broken", because they thought that one test would not start until the prior one finished.

Order could, of course, be changed to work like that. However, at this point, that would be a breaking change for some people, so you most likely won't see it happen until there's an NUnit 4.

So... what can you do as a workaround? I can see three options...

1. The simplest approach would be to make each fixture `[NonParallelizable]`. Then they would all run separately. You should try that first and see if the performance is acceptable to you. If you want the tests within each fixture to run in parallel, you could use `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]` instead but that might break things if the tests change the state of the fixture or of any common references found in the fixture.
2. Alternatively, you could pick only some fixtures to mark as `[NonParallelizable]`. In that case, I'd do it for the ones that consume a lot of memory.
3. For the most effort required, you could implement ordering yourself for these classes. I'd do that by creating some sort of shared token... e.g. a lock... which each class had to acquire on startup. I'd grab the lock in the OneTimeSetUp for a fixture and release it in the onetime teardown. The locking code should be *before* any setup code, which acquires resources and should be released after your teardown releases those resources.

I made option 3 rather sketchy because (a) I don't know precisely how your application works and (b) I presume that you won't do it unless it's absolutely necessary.

Final advice: don't make any assumptions about the performance impact of any of these options, even the first. Measure first!

Comment: thanks again for your detailed answer Charlie! 
I tried the `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]` as i have one test class, which has 2 different test methods for one feature. But they instantly fail somehow, while they run smoothly when run seperately. It would have been great if there was a function which could actually control the `[Parallelizable]` to define orders. Did you work also with xUnit? Do you think it works better? We work on .NET in C#

Comment: In that case, your test methods are not independent and can't run in parallel. Simplest is to not run those fixtures in parallel at all. ParallelAttribute doesn't make tests capable of working in parallel, it only _promises_ to NUnit that they are already capable. Sorry, no information about xunit.